# Problem in facebook login andriod flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, facebook

I have app made in flutter using the source code of fluxstore. Facebook and google were working fine before releasing to google app store. After releasing to app store gmail signin is working fine but facebook give ng error. I also use sha1 converted to hashkeys in facebook developer consel. But problem remians the same

App link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voo.store
[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcS4L.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcS4L.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDHk1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the Facebook key hash for your production Keystore and add it to the Facebook app. If you use your debug key store you will get the above issue.

Comment: Can u elobrate it? I have added both my own release key and google sign key. But error is same. As i told earlier it was working fine with release apk.

Comment: If you have enabled Google to manage your app signing key, you have to add that key hash as well. You can get that key from the 'App Integrity' menu of your app from the Google Play Store Console.

Comment: As i told i add both google and owned key hashed.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's required key hashes are different from the ones in your Firebase console.

Click on this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/398030944614930/fb-login/quickstart/?business_id=210683893235490) and follow step 4. You will have to download a software (openssl) if you are using Windows to generate the key hash. Remember this key hash is different from your key sign.

Comment: Brother i converrt hash1 to hashcode using online site. Still no luck

Comment: You are not supposed to convert anything. Did you follow the instruction on step 4? You are supposed to generate from scratch. My Facebook hash key is different from my firebase console logins

Comment: provided link open facebook developer consel

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/398030944614930/fb-login/quickstart/?business_id=210683893235490

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your output apk files (Usually <project_root>\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk).
2. Use keytools to get the SHA1 value (run in terminal / git bash):

> keytool -printcert -jarfile app-release.apk

3. Convert the HEX(SHA1) value to base64 to get value that ends with [this site](https://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en)
4. Then Update base64 into meta developer